# NP-complete knapsack

Tags: prolog, np-complete, clpfd

I saw [this](http://eclipseclp.org/examples/xkcd287.ecl.txt) ECLiPSe solution to the problem mentioned in [this](http://xkcd.com/287/) XKCD comic.  I tried to convert this to pure Prolog.

```
go:-
    Total = 1505,
    Prices = [215, 275, 335, 355, 420, 580],
    length(Prices, N),
    length(Amounts, N),
    totalCost(Prices, Amounts, 0, Total),
    writeln(Total).

totalCost([], [], TotalSoFar, TotalSoFar).
totalCost([P|Prices], [A|Amounts], TotalSoFar, EndTotal):-
    between(0, 10, A),
    Cost is P*A,
    TotalSoFar1 is TotalSoFar + Cost,
    totalCost(Prices, Amounts, TotalSoFar1, EndTotal).
```

I don't think that this is the best / most declarative solution that one can come up with.  Does anyone have any suggestions for improvement?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems efficient to work backward from the most expensive items, as these permit smaller Amount multiples to be subtracted from the budget/knapsack (less branching).  A simple modification to your existing code would be to check that TotalSoFar is less than or equal to EndTotal.  With this in a pencil and paper attempt, I found a solution pretty quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your generate-and-test approach should be intelligible to any Prolog programmer with more than a few days experience.  Here are some minor tweaks:

```
go(Amounts) :-
    Prices = [580, 420, 355, 335, 275, 215],
    totalCost(Prices, Amounts, 0, 1505),
    write(Amounts), nl.

totalCost([], [], Total, Total).
totalCost([P|Prices], [A|Amounts], SoFar, Total):-
    Upper is (Total-SoFar)//P,
    between(0,Upper,A),
    SoNear is SoFar + P*A,
    totalCost(Prices, Amounts, SoNear, Total).
```

I changed **go/0** to **go/1** so that the Prolog engine will backtrack and produce all the solutions (there are two).  The calls to **length/2** could be omitted because **totalCost/4** does the work of building list Amounts to have equal length with Prices.  I used **write/1** and **nl/0** to make it a little more portable.

In **totalCost/4** I shortened some of the variable/argument names and indulged in a slightly jokey name for the accumulator argument.  The way I imposed the check that our accumulator doesn't exceed the desired Total uses your original call to **between/3** but with a computed upper bound instead of a constant.  On my machine it reduced the running time from minutes to seconds.

**Added:** I should mention here what was said in my comment above, that the menu items are now ordered from most expensive to least.  Using SWI-Prolog's **time/1** predicate shows this reduces the work from 1,923 inferences to 1,070 inferences.  The main improvement (in speed) comes from using computed bounds on A rather than range 0 to 10 for every item.

```
time((go(A),false)).
```

Note the extra parentheses around the compound goal, as otherwise SWI-Prolog thinks we are calling an undefined **time/2** predicate.

Answer (score 6):

Since you mention SWI-Prolog why not

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

and [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl)

```
?- Total = 1505, Prices = [215, 275, 335, 355, 420, 580],
      maplist(\P^A^M^(P*A #= M, A #>=0),Prices,Amounts,Ms),
      sum(Ms, #=, Total).
```

By stating this, all variables in the list `Amounts` are in a finite range. So there is no need to "do the math" for an upper bound (which often goes wrong anyway).
To see concrete solutions, labeling/2 is needed:

```
?- Total = 1505, Prices = [215, 275, 335, 355, 420, 580],
      maplist(\P^A^M^(P*A #= M, A #>=0),Prices,Amounts,Ms),
      sum(Ms, #=, Total),
      labeling([], Amounts).
   Total = 1505, Prices = [215,275,335,355,420,580],
   Amounts = [1,0,0,2,0,1], Ms = [215,0,0,710,0,580]
;  Total = 1505, Prices = [215,275,335,355,420,580],
   Amounts = [7,0,0,0,0,0], Ms = [1505,0,0,0,0,0].
```

Answer (score 0):

Can express simply in [clpBNR](https://github.com/ridgeworks/clpBNR):

```
go :-
    Amounts = [A,B,C,D,E,F],
    Amounts::integer(0, _),
    { (A*215) + (B*275) + (C*335) + (D*355) + (E*420) + (F*580) == 1505 },
    solve(Amounts),
    writeln(Amounts).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(go).
[1,0,0,2,0,1]
% 35,063 inferences, 0.014 CPU in 0.014 seconds (99% CPU, 2483361 Lips)
true ;
[7,0,0,0,0,0]
% 50,954 inferences, 0.023 CPU in 0.023 seconds (100% CPU, 2262260 Lips)
true.
```